# how to get a link coupled with an img to change background color on hover

Tags: html, css

See demo here: [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7k3BT/5/)
I have a table that will contain a series of icons with text underneath each one.
What should happen is that the background and font of the text should change when cursor hovers and the image should be part of the link.

The problem is the paragraph tag used to move text below image.
From the demo:
Link1: link background and font changes. Good, now move the a tag outside img...
Link2: link background doesn't change (?!), font changes, but image is part of link.
Link3: This is the desired behavior but the [a] and [p] tags are mismatched.

Can someone explain
- why the paragraph tag seems to 'block' the background changing color?
- why the mismatched tags allow this to work?
- is there a cleaner way to implement this behavior? (w/o mistmatched tags)

Thanks!

Comment: `src="http://lorempixel.com/g/26/26/" width="26px" height="26px" />link5</a></p></td>` Why not this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p` is not a valid tag inside `a`, because `a` is inline whereas `p` is block.

Fix this by adding `display: inline-block` to `#linkmenu a`.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7k3BT/7/)

Comment: ah thanks!  That makes more sense. Unfortunately now the whole area around image lights up which isn't quite what I was looking for - might have to rethink this.

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/7k3BT/6/

I removed the `<p>` tags around the link text for `link2` and it seems to work fine.

Comment: no guarantee the text remains below the image tho - want to make table without fixed widths